# Is it possible to use aliases when assigning a topic for Google Classroom via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-classroom

I'm trying to create drafts of all my assignments via Google Apps script and group them under different topics that are also created when the script is executed. I have about 20 topics and 80 assignments in total. I've already managed to do it by creating separate `for` loops for each topic where I specify the `topicId`, but it takes many lines of code. Is there a way it can be simplified by using aliases or the topic name when creating an assignment?

This is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
function createAssignments() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Fill This Out!');
  var course = sheet.getRange(11, 7).getValue(); // Assigns the course ID 
  var assignments= ss.getSheetByName('Assignments').getRange(1,1,80,3).getValues();



  var cTitle = ["Topic 1" "Topic 2", "Topic 20"];

 for (var i = 0; i < cTitle.length; i++){
 Classroom.Courses.Topics.create({name:cTitle[i]}, course);
 }

  var getTopics = Classroom.Courses.Topics.list(course); // Gets topic list
  var topics = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < getTopics.topic.length; j++){
    topics.push(getTopics.topic[j].topicId);
  }

  if (assignments[0][2] = "Arithmetic"){
    assignments[0][2] = (topics[0])};


  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({ // Creates a draft of the assignment
    title: ("Basic Arithmetic Pre-Test"), // Title of the assignment
    state: "DRAFT",
    materials: [ {
      link: {
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/yadayada/viewform?usp=sf_link"
      }
    }
               ],
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT",
    topicId: assignment[0][2]
    }, course);
}
```

With this, I can use a multidimensional array to append a topic ID for each assignment, and then create them in a `for` loop. Is there any easier method though?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify if 1) **Arithmetic** is one of the `topicId`s and 2) Are certain assignments correspond to certain specific topics or are all assignments to be aligned with all topics? Basically, if you already have a mapping of which assignments are to be aligned with what topics, you'd not need to intentionally specify `if <> else` statements.

Comment: Arithmetic is one of the topic names. I have a column in my spreadsheet that contains the topics for each assignment. The if statements are used to change that value in the array from the topic name, to the topic ID. How can I map which assignments are aligned with what topics from within the spreadsheet if the topics themselves are created when the script is executed? I'm probably missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out without if else statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as Alias are only for the [Course resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.aliases). The only way is iterating over all the Topic list as you already did. I found this [post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142743371#comment2) in Issue Tracker, while it's not related to your question, the agent explains a bit how Topic retrieving work.